# Error column in default query in JPQL

Tags: java, sqlexception

I am getting the following error while populating data from a database for a Jtable:

```
Internal Exception: java.sql.SQLException: no such column: ERROR
Call: SELECT name, class, adm, year, dob, ERROR FROM STUDENTS
```

here is my query:

```
entityManager = java.beans.Beans.isDesignTime() ? null :  javax.persistence.Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory("jdbc:sqlite:C:\\Users\\Xcoder\\De    sktop\\jtable\\school.dbPU").createEntityManager();
    studentsQuery = java.beans.Beans.isDesignTime() ? null :     entityManager.createQuery("SELECT s FROM Students s");
    studentsList = java.beans.Beans.isDesignTime() ? java.util.Collections.emptyList() : studentsQuery.getResultList();
    jScrollPane1 = new javax.swing.JScrollPane();
    jTable1 = new javax.swing.JTable();
```

My question is where could this error column being called?

Answer (score 0):

Does your `Students` object contain an `error` field?  If so, and if you haven't marked it as `@Transient` or some such, it will be used as a column in your query.

I might also suggest cleaning up your code a bit, e.g.:

```
if (Beans.isDesignTime()) {
    entityManager = Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory("jdbc:sqlite:C:\\Users\\Xcoder\\De    sktop\\jtable\\school.dbPU").createEntityManager();
    studentsQuery = entityManager.createQuery("SELECT s FROM Students s");
    studentsList = studentsQuery.getResultList();
} else {
    studentsList = Collections.emptyList();
}
```

Not sure why you're using `Beans.isDesignTime()` either, that's a bit of an odd thing to check for.  That's typically used by IDEs to check whether you're designing a GUI.